# bash pipe vs here-string

Tags: bash, pipe

I tought these command were equivalent in bash, but they are producing different outputs.
Could you help me understand why?

```
$ echo "SEBA" | wc
      1       1       5
```

```
$ wc <<< "SEBA"
1 1 5
```

Running on

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- wc (GNU coreutils) 8.30

here are some tests:

```
$ echo "SEBA" | wc | hexdump 
0000000 2020 2020 2020 2031 2020 2020 2020 2031
0000010 2020 2020 2020 0a35                    
0000018
```

```
$ wc <<< "SEBA" | hexdump 
0000000 2031 2031 0a35                         
0000006
```

```
$ echo "SEBA" | hexdump 
0000000 4553 4142 000a                         
0000005
```

```
$ hexdump <<< "SEBA"
0000000 4553 4142 000a                         
0000005
```

Comment: What shell are you using? Both produce identical output on my system, using bash 5.1.

Comment: I can't reproduce that output from the herestring. which version of bash?

Comment: The are not identical, but I have trouble explaining why the difference would affect the *output* of `wc`. (This is specific to the Linux `coreutils` version of `wc`; I cannot reproduce the difference with the BSD version on macOS.)

Comment: Try opening a new shell/terminal window and running it there.  What you're seeing sounds implausible.  I wonder if it could be an issue with the size of tab stops — though I'm clutching at straws here?  Are the commands run consecutively?  Nominally, the problem should be in `wc`.  Have you tried running the output of `wc` through a hex dump program?  Does it change?  What spacing characters are used?  If you look at the POSIX specification of [`wc`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html) under 'STDOUT', you'll see that the output should be based on `"%d %d %d\n"`.

Comment: I note that on macOS, the output from `wc` in effect uses `" %7d %7d %7d\n" as the format — the numbers are printed in fields 8 characters wide (until you process massive files).

Comment: Just for confirmation: I *can* reproduce this (CentOS7, bash 4.2.46(2), wc 8.22)

Comment: I reproduced this on Debian with wc 8.30.

Comment: I think it's because here-strings use a temporary file, not a pipe. `wc` formats its output differently depending on where it's getting the input.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, and indeed you get the herestring output if you do `echo "SEBA" > file ; wc < file`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When GNU `wc` gets all its input from files, it uses `stat()` (or `fstat()` for `stdin`) to get the sizes of the all the files in characters. From this it can determine the maximum number digits needed for each output field, and only uses that many digits.

When any of the inputs is a pipe, it's not possible to determine its size ahead of time. It defaults to 7 digits for that input.

Here-strings are implemented by copying the string to a temporary file and redirecting stdin to that file, so this case is able to use the optimized field size. But piping from `echo` doesn't permit this, so it gets 7-digit fields.

See the functions [`get_input_fstatus`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/wc.c#L725) and [`compute_number_width`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/wc.c#L751) in the GNU coreutils source.

As noted in a comment, `bash 5.1` doesn't use a temporary for small here-strings or here-documents, it uses a pipe. "Small" may not be very small, it's the pipe buffer size. As explained at [How big is the pipe buffer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer), this defaults to 16K on Mac OS X and 64K on Linux. So you shouldn't depend on this behavior portably between `bash` versions.

Comment: Can this be considered a design flaw of `wc` ? Be it file or pipe, `wc` prints the result only at the very end, when file or pipe is fully read, so it should have the same information in both cases.

Comment: what's the flaw? It's printing the same information, the only difference is the number of spaces between the values, which isn't part of the spec.

Comment: The reason it doesn't wait until the pipe is fully read is because there could be many pipes. It would have to save all the results until it has processed every input.

Comment: Remember, some of the inputs could be named pipes or process substitutions, so it's not just one pipe.

Comment: `wc file1 file2 file3` will print the results from `file1` before reading `file2`.

Comment: @Barmar - regarding *Here-strings are implemented by copying the string to a temporary file [...]*: [As of bash 5.1, here-strings may not create a temporary file as long as they are small enough](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-5.1#n13).

Comment: @Abdull Good catch, I've updated the answer.