# How here document works in shell

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

While doing the input redirection, the shell opens the file on the right side of '<' with file descriptor 0, but in the case of the heredoc there is no such file to open, I am wondering what exactly shell does in this case.

```
cat > file.txt << EOF
line1
line2
EOF
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In bash 5.0 and older, it creates a temporary file, writes the heredoc contents, and then redirects that file to stdin.

We can see this happen with `strace`, which shows syscalls. Here are the relevant portions annotated with inline comments:

```
$ strace -f bash -c $'cat > file.txt << EOF\nline1\nline2\nEOF'

# Open a temporary file `/tmp/sh-thd-1641928925`.
[pid  8292] open("/tmp/sh-thd-1641928925", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_TRUNC, 0600) = 3

# Write the heredoc contents to the file.
[pid  8292] dup(3)                      = 4
[pid  8292] write(4, "line1\nline2\n", 12) = 12
[pid  8292] close(4)                    = 0

# Open the file read-only.
[pid  8292] open("/tmp/sh-thd-1641928925", O_RDONLY) = 4

# Close the original file and unlink it so there's no filesystem
# reference. The file will be fully deleted once all fds are closed.
[pid  8292] close(3)                    = 0
[pid  8292] unlink("/tmp/sh-thd-1641928925") = 0

# Redirect the file to stdin.
[pid  8292] dup2(4, 0)                  = 0
[pid  8292] close(4)                    = 0

# Execute `cat`.
[pid  8292] execve("/usr/bin/cat", ["cat"], 0x187c160 /* 113 vars */) = 0
```

Answer (score 9):

Until `bash 5.1`, it copies the contents of the here-document to a temporary file, then redirects input to that file.

Since 5.1, it depends on how large the here-document is. If it fits into the pipe buffer, it creates a pipe and writes the contents of the here-document to the pipe. If it's too large for this, it reverts to the temporary file method.

Comment: Does that mean the command might run in a subshell since 5.1, e.g. after `x=7; while IFS= read -r y; do x="$y"; done <<EOF<newline>23<newline>EOF` running `echo "$x"` might output `7` instead of `23` like it would if I wrote `x=7; echo 23 | while IFS= read -r y; do x="$y"; done; echo "$x"`?

Comment: I don't think so. That's the reason for it having to fit into the pipe buffer, so that `write()` won't block and it won't deadlock.

Comment: And see [how big is the pipe buffer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer) -- some pretty large here-documents can be optimized like this.

Comment: Thanks. Mainly I just don't want the output to depend on how much input there is like it would if bash 5.1 treated the pipe you mention the same way as a hand-written pipe and put the command reading the input into a subshell.

Comment: If the command behaves differently depending on whether its input is a pipe or file, you'll see differently. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68226426/bash-pipe-vs-here-string/68227338#68227338) where `wc` produces different output.

Comment: Hmm, that's not ideal either but what I'm really concerned about is whether the value of a variable set during reading input in a loop from a here doc will or will not retain that value once the loop is ended. If the answer is "depends how much input there is" then that's not good! If that's the case then hopefully there's a rule of thumb written somewhere that says "don't write large here docs so the result is always predictable and don't assume the value of a variable set while reading from one in a loop will be available after the loop".

Comment: The more I think about this the more it seems like a bad decision on the part of the bash folks. If I wanted a pipe I could always trivially write `echo foo | while read` so why take away the ability to write `while read ... <<EOF\nfoo\nEOF` and have the loop run in the current shell? I guess I'll need to play with this if/when I install bash 5.1 - maybe they don't use a subshell (hopefully!) but still, making it behave like a pipe has got to introduce breakage for commands that behave differently with piped vs file input as you described.

Comment: AFAIK it has never been specified what mechanism here-documents use. The point is to make the syntax simpler, and lots of `echo` with a pipe is not simple.

Comment: Using a temp file versus a pipe has always been an implementation detail that applications shouldn't care about.

Comment: What does this have to do with a subshell? I'm pretty sure there's no difference there.

Comment: When you set a variable in a subshell such as occurs when reading the output of a pipe in a loop, that variables value is not retained after the loop, e.g. `x=7; echo '23' | while IFS= read -r y; do x="$y"; done; echo "$x"` would output `7` whereas if you read from a file (or a here-string or here-doc that's implemented as a temp file) then the loop does not occur in a subshell, and so any variable set in the loop retains it's value after it, e.g. `x=7; while IFS= read -r y; do x="$y"; done <<<'23'; echo "$x"` would output `23`.

Comment: I know all that. Why do you think that implementing the here-document using a pipe would require a subshell?

Comment: There's nothing that prevents writing and reading the pipe in the same process.

Comment: This is supposed to be a transparent implementation detail. It shouldn't have any effect on variable scope.

Comment: Regarding `why do you think` - because in bash a loop that reads from a pipeline is put in a subshell, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024.

Comment: You're confusing a pipe with a command pipeline.

Comment: I've never heard of a difference between "reading from a pipe" and "reading from a pipeline".

Comment: A pipeline is when you write `command1 | command2` in the shell. A pipe is calling the `pipe()` system call inside a C program.

Comment: The latter is used to implement the former, but it's not limited to that use.

Comment: and then a while loop reading from a pipe is different from a while loop reading from a pipeline?

Comment: Yes, because the shell runs the loop in the main process, not a subshell. Which was the answer I gave you when you first asked if it causes a subshell.

Comment: OK, good to know, thanks.

Comment: Because it's not writing to the pipe in a loop. It only does this for small input, which it can write in one single call.

Comment: this is breaking my code in the case where command performs stat on the filename to needlessly make sure that it is a real file: command /dev/fd/3 3<<<"$data"

Comment: Unfortunately, these optimizations made by the shell can cause inconsistent behavior with programs that behave differently depending on whether the input is a file or pipe.

Comment: Yes, one of these programs is `logrotate /dev/stdin <<< $'filename { size 1M\n rotate 9\n }'` which worked before bash 5.1 and now prints `Ignoring /dev/stdin because it's not a regular file`.