# Bash process substitution fails because pipe is not seekable

Tags: linux, bash

I have a program that takes a file as input and must determine it's size. I'm trying to use process substitution with a variable to provide that file, but since process substitution creates a file descriptor that belongs to a pipe, the program fails to seek it and doesn't work.

Specifically:

```
$ ./my_program --input-file <(echo $data)
Error: illegal seek.
```

Are there any easy way around this? I could use `mktemp` to create a file and write to it before passing the file, but I'm hoping there's a better way. Seems like I would need to create some sort of seekable wrapper around the file descriptor, but I don't know of any easy way to do that that doesn't create dependencies.

Comment: There's no built-in way to do it. The temp file is the correct solution.

Comment: If you really want to be able to use your program like this, you should redesign it so it doesn't need to seek. It could check if the file is seekable, and if not it could copy the contents to a temp file itself.

Comment: Standard tools (`tail`, `tac`, etc) have fallback logic to use when seeking fails (at the cost of worse performance / more memory usage / tempfile creation / etc). It's more work, but that's generally considered the Right Thing.

Comment: There's no better way in Bash, but Zsh has `=(cmd)`.

Comment: Finding the file size (if available) shouldn't be done with seek anyways. That's what `stat()` and `fstat()` are for.

Comment: All good comments above, but to me there are a lot of questions here. Is `./my_program` a shell script, or a `c` compiled program or ?? ... You say ` takes a file as input`, but you use `<(echo $data)`. What is in `$data`? A filename? If so, wouldn't you want to use `cat $data` instead of `echo`? Or if a file, alternately why can't your `--input-file` just handle a /path/to/filename as a regular argument? And rather than reply in comments, please consider updating the body of your question, so then I can remove this comment. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter `<(cmd)` expands to the filename of a pipe/fifo that is connected to `cmd`'s standard output. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html

Comment: @shawn : yes, I see that, but what we have from O.P. doesn't really qualify as a [mcve], (which I realized too late that  I should have included a reference to in my original comment). Good luck to all.

Comment: If the program can’t be modified to process a stream of data without seeking, then the only way forward is (indeed) to “materialize” the file.

Comment: @shellter So you could `./my_program --input-file < <(echo $data)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If (and only if) you are running Bash 5.0 or **older** then this should work:

```
./my_program --input-file /dev/stdin <<<"$data"
```

- `<<<"$data"` is a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings). It causes the value of `$data`, with an added trailing newline, to be provided as standard input to the command.  In Bash 5.0 and earlier it is implemented by writing the data to a temporary file and opening the file as standard input for the command.  See [How here document works in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70672456/4154375).  (That describes the implementation for a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents), but it's the same for a here string.)
- `/dev/stdin` acts like a link to the input file.  When the input file is a regular file (as with the temporary file used for a here string in Bash 5.0 and older) `/dev/stdin` is seekable.
- Unfortunately, this code is a solution for your problem only if you can guarantee that it will never be run by a version of Bash newer than 5.0.  If you can't modify `my_program`, your best practical option is probably to use `mktemp` to create a temporary file explicitly.

Comment: Interesting! I didn’t know that Bash at some point materialized here-documents. Exactly as you say, it no longer works with `5.2.15`. With a C one-liner called `seek` (`#include <unistd.h>` `int main() { return lseek(STDIN_FILENO, 0, SEEK_SET); }`), `./seek < /proc/cpuinfo` works, but `./seek <<< blah` fails. That Bash change would have been quite a showstopper if any of my scripts had relied on this behavior. (Fortunately they didn’t .)