# How to make a command stop expecting input if heredoc delimiter is ""?

Tags: bash, shell, posix, heredoc

In a POSIX shell (let's consider bash in this example), whenever we run `cmd << eof`, the shell expects input until a string containing only `eof` is received. Also, the standard states that:

> If any part of word [delimiter] is quoted, the delimiter shall be formed by performing quote removal on word, and the here-document lines shall not be expanded. Otherwise, the delimiter shall be the word itself.

So, in an exercise of curiosity, I tried running the following command: `cat << ""` aaaaand I cannot make the shell stop waiting for input. I imagine that the quotes were removed and, as nothing is left, nothing in fact is the delimiter of the heredoc.

I have tried sending the following strings: `"`, `""`, `\0`, etc.

The only way to get out, is, as far as I know it, through a signal that terminates the process.

**My question is: is there a way to 'properly' tell the shell to stop expecting input in this situation?**

Comment: The shell expects input until a string containing only **the delimiter** is received. If the delimiter is empty, what are you going to provide to end the heredoc?

Comment: @pmf exactly my thoughts. So the only way out is through heterodox means?

Comment: @pmf ooooooooh, i see it. Just sending an empty string (pressing ENTER) works. DUH!

Comment: I think the "proper" solution is to not use an empty delimiter in the first place. The fact that it work seems to be an unintended side effect of the empty string *needing* to be quoted in order to exist. I haven't found a shell that doesn't treat `cat <<` as a syntax error.

Comment: @chepner , after pmf's comment I just tried hitting ENTER. As I understand, bash uses readline to process input string and readline deletes the \n at the end of the string, passing an empy string to the shell, which matches de delimiter in this case, liberating the shell to execute the command.

So there is not an unintended side effect. It works at it should, apparently.

Comment: No, that's consistent. What I meant was that there is no corresponding way to provide an *unquoted* empty string as a delimiter in the first place, not that special code was needed to terminate a here document started with an empty delimiter.

Comment: You can send ^D

Comment: Readline is irrelevant, since it's not used in scripts, only interactive shells.

Comment: @Barmar I did not know that. Can you point out where I can find how bash implements the processing of heredocs?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70672456/how-here-document-works-in-shell/70672524#70672524.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat << ""` (contrary to many syntax-highlighting routines) starts a "paragraph" heredoc; the first empty line terminates the heredoc:

```bash
cat << ""
lines here
will be
piped to
cat
$this_variable_does_not_expand
`neither does this`

# Back to the script
ls -la
```

In my coding habits, I always use a delimiter.

If you've typed `cat << ""` in your interactive shell, you can halt it by typing <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> or pressing enter twice.